# Dynamic value for message selector camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I have 2 publisher instance and IN topic which consumed by 2 consumer server instance. Consumer replies with status on to a reply queue. Now the publisher which published the message should only get the reply message and do further processing. Since camel doesnot support dynamic value in message selector any idea on how to do  this. I insist for dynamic value in message selector rather than static one, the publisher instance will be scaled horizontally to 3 or 4 or 5 in future.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can the message from the publisher not contain a dynamically populated reply-to header, so the consumer knows where send the reply?

Comment: Thanks. It is not dynamic reply to, all the reply message will go to same queue. So only the publisher who published should take this reply message from queue.

Comment: See the JMS docs about using a shared reply queue